# How to convert Tuple to AnyObject in Swift

Tags: swift, tuples

Following piece of code compiles with error: `Error:(112, 20) type '(String, Int)' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'`

```
func myMethode() {
    aMethodeThatICanNotChange {
        let a  = ("John",7)
        return a  // Error:(112, 20) type '(String, Int)' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'
    }
}

func aMethodeThatICanNotChange(closure: () -> AnyObject) {
     // do something with closure
}
```

How can I cast/convert a Tuple to AnyObject?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can I cast/convert a Tuple to AnyObject?

Simply put, you can't. Only class types (or types that are bridged to Foundation class types) can be cast to AnyObject. A tuple is not a class type.

Of course there may be lots of other ways to accomplish whatever you're *really* trying to accomplish. But as for your *particular* question, you can't do it.

Answer (score 10):

### This is just a workaround.

You can create a class to wrap your tuple.

```
class TupleWrapper {
    let tuple : (String, Int)
    init(tuple : (String, Int)) {
        self.tuple = tuple
    }
}
```

Then you can write this:

```
func myMethod() {
    aMethodeThatICanNotChange {
        let a  = ("John",7)
        let myTupleWrapper = TupleWrapper(tuple: a)
        return myTupleWrapper
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can create a generic wrapper that can receive a value of any `Type`.

```
class GenericWrapper<T> {
    let element : T
    init(element : T) {
        self.element = element
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot... The GenericWrapper works great as a workaround

Answer (score 1):

A tuple is an ordered list of elements, so you can transform it into an `Array` which conforms to `AnyObject` protocol

```
func myMethode() {
    aMethodeThatICanNotChange {
        // let a  = ("John",7)
        let b = ["Joth", 7]

        return b  // No error
    }
}

func aMethodeThatICanNotChange(closure: () -> AnyObject) {
    // do something with closure

}
```