# Create thread safe array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, multithreading, read-write

I have a threading problem in Swift. I have an array with some objects in it. Over a delegate the class gets new objects about every second. After that I have to check if the objects are already in the array, so I have to update the object, otherwise I have to delete / add the new object.

If I add a new object I have to fetch some data over the network first. This is handelt via a block.

Now my problem is, how to I synchronic this tasks?

I have tried a dispatch_semaphore, but this one blocks the UI, until the block is finished.

I have also tried a simple bool variable, which checks if the block is currently executed and skips the compare method meanwhile.

But both methods are not ideal.

What's the best way to manage the array, I don't wanna have duplicate data in the array.

Comment: If you don't want a duplicate data in your Array, you use Set

Answer (score 125):

**Update for Swift**

The recommended pattern for thread-safe access is using dispatch `barrier`:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "thread-safe-obj", attributes: .concurrent)

// write
queue.async(flags: .barrier) {
    // perform writes on data
}

// read
var value: ValueType!
queue.sync {
    // perform read and assign value
}
return value
```

Comment: Thanks, but what are the advantages/disadvantages of objc_sync_enter vs dispatch_queue?

Comment: `objc_sync_enter` is what's underneath Objective-C's `@synchronized`.  Since I haven't really looked at what's underneath `objc_sync_enter` I am sort of trusting that the open source code works as promised. As for using serial queue, you know exactly how that is working (blocks of codes sequentially).  I am guessing the downside of creating and managing a serial queue per thread safe collection type instance could be costly.

Comment: You got me curious, so I found this on `objc_sync_enter`: http://rykap.com/objective-c/2015/05/09/synchronized/

Comment: this works perfect for tuples and NON AnyObject if you have Wrapper class like here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28140922/1264893

Comment: It's not safe/correct to use `objc_sync_enter` on a value type such as `Array`. `objc_sync_array` does pointer comparison and the lifetime of the pointer of a bridged Swift value type is not guaranteed to be stable (and in fact most of the time it is *not* stable).

Comment: @skim I wonder if we can do it like to?
Will it save some hassel?

```
var name: String? {
        set {
            objc_sync_enter(innerName)
            innerName = newValue
            objc_sync_exit(innerName)
        }
        
        get {
            objc_sync_enter(innerName)
            let newValue = innerName
            objc_sync_exit(innerName)
            return newValue
        }
    }
    
private(set) var innerName: String?
```

Comment: this not working, reason    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35084754/objc-sync-enter-objc-sync-exit-not-working-with-dispatch-queue-priority-low

Comment: Just wondering should we capture the self weakly in the blocks? Or is it fine and won't create retain cycle?

Answer (score 68):

I don't know why people take such complex approaches to such a simple thing

- Don't abuse `DispatchQueues` for locking. Using `queue.sync` is nothing more than acquiring a lock and dispatching work to another thread while the lock (`DispatchGroup`) waits. It is not just unnecessary, but also can have side effects depending on what you are locking. You can look it up yourself in the [GCD Source](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/master/src/queue.c).

  *Also GCD does not mix well with the new structured concurrency APIs!*
- Don't use `objc_sync_enter/exit`, those are used by ObjCs `@synchronized` which will implicitly bridge Swift collections to a ObjC counterpart, which is also unnecessary. And it is a legacy API.

Just define a lock, and guard your collection access.

```
var lock = NSLock()
var a = [1, 2, 3]

lock.lock()
a.append(4)
lock.unlock()
```

If you want to make your life a bit easier, define a small extension.

```
extension NSLock {

    @discardableResult
    func with<T>(_ block: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
        lock()
        defer { unlock() }
        return try block()
    }
}

let lock = NSLock()
var a = [1, 2, 3]

lock.with { a.append(4) }
```

You can also define a `@propertyWrapper` to make your member `var`s atomic.

```
@propertyWrapper
struct Atomic<Value> {

    private let lock = NSLock()
    private var value: Value

    init(default: Value) {
        self.value = `default`
    }

    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get {
            lock.lock()
            defer { lock.unlock() }
            return value
        }
        set {
            lock.lock()
            defer { lock.unlock() }
            value = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Last but not least for primitive atomic types there is also [**Swift Atomics**](https://github.com/apple/swift-atomics)

Comment: It seems that adding a call to .lock() within the willSet property observer (and a corresponding .unlock() in didSet) works. This means you don't have to make any other code changes at call sites. (If you remove the call to .unlock() you can confirm that this does work). I imagine you could probably create a property wrapper for this too.

Comment: Yes, you could make a @propertyWrapper too

Comment: @rennarda if it will crash during a set, it will never unlock in `didSet`.

Comment: Heads up, the property wrapper won't work for any `Collection`, including Array.

https://www.donnywals.com/why-your-atomic-property-wrapper-doesnt-work-for-collection-types/

Comment: @AlexanderVolkov If it crashes during a set, then any thread locks are no longer relevant— the process and all threads are forceably ended by the kernel.  Did you mean “if it will throw an exception during as set”?

Answer (score 40):

Kirsteins's answer is correct, but for convenience, I've updated that answer with Amol Chaudhari and Rob's suggestions for using a concurrent queue with async barrier to allow concurrent reads but block on writes.

I've also wrapped some other array functions that were useful to me.

```
public class SynchronizedArray<T> {
private var array: [T] = []
private let accessQueue = dispatch_queue_create("SynchronizedArrayAccess", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)

public func append(newElement: T) {
    dispatch_barrier_async(self.accessQueue) {
        self.array.append(newElement)
    }
}

public func removeAtIndex(index: Int) {
    dispatch_barrier_async(self.accessQueue) {
        self.array.removeAtIndex(index)
    }
}

public var count: Int {
    var count = 0

    dispatch_sync(self.accessQueue) {
        count = self.array.count
    }

    return count
}

public func first() -> T? {
    var element: T?

    dispatch_sync(self.accessQueue) {
        if !self.array.isEmpty {
            element = self.array[0]
        }
    }

    return element
}

public subscript(index: Int) -> T {
    set {
        dispatch_barrier_async(self.accessQueue) {
            self.array[index] = newValue
        }
    }
    get {
        var element: T!

        dispatch_sync(self.accessQueue) {
            element = self.array[index]
        }

        return element
    }
}
}
```

**UPDATE**
This is the same code, updated for Swift3.

```
public class SynchronizedArray<T> {
private var array: [T] = []
private let accessQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "SynchronizedArrayAccess", attributes: .concurrent)

public func append(newElement: T) {

    self.accessQueue.async(flags:.barrier) {
        self.array.append(newElement)
    }
}

public func removeAtIndex(index: Int) {

    self.accessQueue.async(flags:.barrier) {
        self.array.remove(at: index)
    }
}

public var count: Int {
    var count = 0

    self.accessQueue.sync {
        count = self.array.count
    }

    return count
}

public func first() -> T? {
    var element: T?

    self.accessQueue.sync {
        if !self.array.isEmpty {
            element = self.array[0]
        }
    }

    return element
}

public subscript(index: Int) -> T {
    set {
        self.accessQueue.async(flags:.barrier) {
            self.array[index] = newValue
        }
    }
    get {
        var element: T!
        self.accessQueue.sync {
            element = self.array[index]
        }

        return element
    }
}
}
```

Comment: removeAtIndex could remove wrong item in this code cause idx cold be changed by other thread 'removeAtIndex' ...

Comment: @Speakus could be wrong but I'm pretty sure it doesn't. It's async, but on the same concurrent queue as other array operations... so the removeAtIndex will happen before any other read or write operation happens.

Comment: @JordanSmith The issue will happen when you call removeAtIndex but code will switch to another thread for example in time when you get self.accessQueue but before .async running.

Comment: Can you please explain how to use this SynchronizedArray class in place of normal swift 3 array ([String] or []) ? It's very urgent

Comment: Use it like an array in a class that can be accessed from multiple threads.  
let array = SynchronizedArray<String>()
array.append("New string")
print(array[0])
array.removeAtIndex(index: 0)
print(array.count)

Comment: This should be the correct answer. `objc_sync_enter`/`exit` won't give you concurrent reads and @rmooneys answer is pure Swift

Comment: @mooney I think @Speakus is right here: Say the sychronized array has one element, wouldn't this fail? `if synchronizedArray.count == 1 { synchronizedArray.remove(at: 0) }` It's a race condition, say two threads execute the statement. Both read a count of 1 concurrently, both enqueue a write block concurrently. The write blocks execute sequentially, the second one will fail. Am I wrong? Is this a designer or user error? In either case It's fragile as hell & making me never want to touch multi-threading... How would you even make this safe? Back to exclusive locks for both reading and writing?

Comment: @tombardey - You are absolutely right that this level of synchronization (at the property/method level) is frequently insufficient to achieve true thread-safety in broader applications. Your example is easily solved (by adding an method that dispatches block to the queue), but there are others that aren't (e.g. "synchronized" array simultaneously used by a `UITableViewDataSource` and mutated by some background operation). In those cases, you have to implement your own higher-level synchronization. But the above technique is nonetheless very useful in certain, highly constrained situations.

Comment: @rmooney - In your Swift 3 and 4 examples, you can simplify some of those routines, eliminating the implicitly unwrapped optionals, e.g. `var first: T? { return accessQueue.sync { self.array.first } }`

Answer (score 36):

My approach to this problem was using serial dispatch queue, to synchronise access to boxed array. It will block the thread when you try to get the value at index and queue is really busy, but that's the problem with locks as well.

```
public class SynchronizedArray<T> {
    private var array: [T] = []
    private let accessQueue = dispatch_queue_create("SynchronizedArrayAccess", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

    public func append(newElement: T) {
        dispatch_async(self.accessQueue) {
            self.array.append(newElement)
        }
    }

    public subscript(index: Int) -> T {
        set {
            dispatch_async(self.accessQueue) {
                self.array[index] = newValue
            }
        }
        get {
            var element: T!

            dispatch_sync(self.accessQueue) {
                element = self.array[index]
            }

            return element
        }
    }
}

var a = SynchronizedArray<Int>()
a.append(1)
a.append(2)
a.append(3)

// can be empty as this is non-thread safe access
println(a.array)

// thread-safe synchonized access
println(a[0])
println(a[1])
println(a[2])
```

Comment: You might consider using reader-writer pattern: Use `DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT`; changing writes from `dispatch_async` to `dispatch_barrier_async`; but leaving reads as `dispatch_sync`. This gives you concurrent reading, but writes are still synchronized.

Comment: How would you pass in a sort for custom types?

Comment: Doesn't a `DispatchQueue` require the CPU to do a context switch to another thread, thus resulting in a very expensive operation? Or is it `sync()` that actually solves this problem by not dispatching to the queue if not necessary because it's a read-only resource access?

Answer (score 10):

## Thread-safe Data Structures with Actors

As of Swift 5.5 you can express this with an actor:

```swift
actor SyncArray<T> {
    private var buffer: [T]
    
    init<S: Sequence>(_ elements: S) where S.Element == T {
        buffer = Array(elements)
    }
    
    var count: Int {
        buffer.count
    }
    
    func append(_ element: T) {
        buffer.append(element)
    }
    
    @discardableResult
    func remove(at index: Int) -> T {
        buffer.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

Not only it makes the code simpler and less error prone, but it makes more explicit the potential race condition pointed out in an other answer:

```swift
Task {
    let array = SyncArray([1])

    if await array.count == 1 { 
        await array.remove(at: 0)
    }
}
```

There are two suspension points here, meaning that by the time `.remove(at:)` is called, the array `count` could have changed.

Such read-then-write operation must be atomic to be consistent, thus it should be defined as a method on the actor instead:

```swift
extension SyncArray {
    func removeLastIfSizeOfOne() {
        if buffer.count == 1 {
            buffer.remove(at: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Above, the absence of suspension points indicates that the operation is performed atomically. Another solution that works without writing an extension is to use the `isolated` keyword like this:

```swift
func removeLastIfSizeOfOne<T>(_ array: isolated SyncArray<T>) {
    if array.count == 1 {
        array.remove(at: 0)
    }
}
```

This will isolate the passed actor for the duration of the whole call instead of at each of its suspension points. Calling this function requires only one suspension point.

Comment: Would it work if you add a subscript method?

Comment: It works with a read-only subscript but I wasn’t able to use a subscript setter.

Comment: what error did you get ?

Comment: "Actor-isolated subscript can not be mutated from the main actor/Sendable closure" depending on where I run the code.

Comment: I may be wrong but it looks like a Swift bug to me. The subscript should be run on the actor like any other instance method of an actor.

Answer (score 9):

### Details

- Xcode 10.1 (10B61), Swift 4.2
- Xcode 10.2.1 (10E1001), Swift 5

### Solution

```
import Foundation

// https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection
struct AtomicArray<T>: RangeReplaceableCollection {

    typealias Element = T
    typealias Index = Int
    typealias SubSequence = AtomicArray<T>
    typealias Indices = Range<Int>
    fileprivate var array: Array<T>
    var startIndex: Int { return array.startIndex }
    var endIndex: Int { return array.endIndex }
    var indices: Range<Int> { return array.indices }

    func index(after i: Int) -> Int { return array.index(after: i) }

    private var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
    fileprivate func _wait() { semaphore.wait() }
    fileprivate func _signal() { semaphore.signal() }
}

// MARK: - Instance Methods

extension AtomicArray {

    init<S>(_ elements: S) where S : Sequence, AtomicArray.Element == S.Element {
        array = Array<S.Element>(elements)
    }

    init() { self.init([]) }

    init(repeating repeatedValue: AtomicArray.Element, count: Int) {
        let array = Array(repeating: repeatedValue, count: count)
        self.init(array)
    }
}

// MARK: - Instance Methods

extension AtomicArray {

    public mutating func append(_ newElement: AtomicArray.Element) {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        array.append(newElement)
    }

    public mutating func append<S>(contentsOf newElements: S) where S : Sequence, AtomicArray.Element == S.Element {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        array.append(contentsOf: newElements)
    }

    func filter(_ isIncluded: (AtomicArray.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> AtomicArray {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        let subArray = try array.filter(isIncluded)
        return AtomicArray(subArray)
    }

    public mutating func insert(_ newElement: AtomicArray.Element, at i: AtomicArray.Index) {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        array.insert(newElement, at: i)
    }

    mutating func insert<S>(contentsOf newElements: S, at i: AtomicArray.Index) where S : Collection, AtomicArray.Element == S.Element {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        array.insert(contentsOf: newElements, at: i)
    }

    mutating func popLast() -> AtomicArray.Element? {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        return array.popLast()
    }

    @discardableResult mutating func remove(at i: AtomicArray.Index) -> AtomicArray.Element {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        return array.remove(at: i)
    }

    mutating func removeAll() {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        array.removeAll()
    }

    mutating func removeAll(keepingCapacity keepCapacity: Bool) {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        array.removeAll()
    }

    mutating func removeAll(where shouldBeRemoved: (AtomicArray.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        try array.removeAll(where: shouldBeRemoved)
    }

    @discardableResult mutating func removeFirst() -> AtomicArray.Element {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        return array.removeFirst()
    }

    mutating func removeFirst(_ k: Int) {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        array.removeFirst(k)
    }

    @discardableResult mutating func removeLast() -> AtomicArray.Element {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        return array.removeLast()
    }

    mutating func removeLast(_ k: Int) {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        array.removeLast(k)
    }

    @inlinable public func forEach(_ body: (Element) throws -> Void) rethrows {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        try array.forEach(body)
    }

    mutating func removeFirstIfExist(where shouldBeRemoved: (AtomicArray.Element) throws -> Bool) {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        guard let index = try? array.firstIndex(where: shouldBeRemoved) else { return }
        array.remove(at: index)
    }

    mutating func removeSubrange(_ bounds: Range<Int>) {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        array.removeSubrange(bounds)
    }

    mutating func replaceSubrange<C, R>(_ subrange: R, with newElements: C) where C : Collection, R : RangeExpression, T == C.Element, AtomicArray<Element>.Index == R.Bound {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        array.replaceSubrange(subrange, with: newElements)
    }

    mutating func reserveCapacity(_ n: Int) {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        array.reserveCapacity(n)
    }

    public var count: Int {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        return array.count
    }

    public var isEmpty: Bool {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        return array.isEmpty
    }
}

// MARK: - Get/Set

extension AtomicArray {

    // Single  action

    func get() -> [T] {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        return array
    }

    mutating func set(array: [T]) {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        self.array = array
    }

    // Multy actions

    mutating func get(closure: ([T])->()) {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        closure(array)
    }

    mutating func set(closure: ([T]) -> ([T])) {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        array = closure(array)
    }
}

// MARK: - Subscripts

extension AtomicArray {

    subscript(bounds: Range<AtomicArray.Index>) -> AtomicArray.SubSequence {
        get {
            _wait(); defer { _signal() }
            return AtomicArray(array[bounds])
        }
    }

    subscript(bounds: AtomicArray.Index) -> AtomicArray.Element {
        get {
            _wait(); defer { _signal() }
            return array[bounds]
        }
        set(value) {
            _wait(); defer { _signal() }
            array[bounds] = value
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Operator Functions

extension AtomicArray {

    static func + <Other>(lhs: Other, rhs: AtomicArray) -> AtomicArray where Other : Sequence, AtomicArray.Element == Other.Element {
        return AtomicArray(lhs + rhs.get())
    }

    static func + <Other>(lhs: AtomicArray, rhs: Other) -> AtomicArray where Other : Sequence, AtomicArray.Element == Other.Element {
        return AtomicArray(lhs.get() + rhs)
    }

    static func + <Other>(lhs: AtomicArray, rhs: Other) -> AtomicArray where Other : RangeReplaceableCollection, AtomicArray.Element == Other.Element {
        return AtomicArray(lhs.get() + rhs)
    }

    static func + (lhs: AtomicArray<Element>, rhs: AtomicArray<Element>) -> AtomicArray {
        return AtomicArray(lhs.get() + rhs.get())
    }

    static func += <Other>(lhs: inout AtomicArray, rhs: Other) where Other : Sequence, AtomicArray.Element == Other.Element {
        lhs._wait(); defer { lhs._signal() }
        lhs.array += rhs
    }
}

// MARK: - CustomStringConvertible

extension AtomicArray: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        return "\(array)"
    }
}

// MARK: - Equatable

extension AtomicArray where Element : Equatable {

    func split(separator: Element, maxSplits: Int, omittingEmptySubsequences: Bool) -> [ArraySlice<Element>] {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        return array.split(separator: separator, maxSplits: maxSplits, omittingEmptySubsequences: omittingEmptySubsequences)
    }

    func firstIndex(of element: Element) -> Int? {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        return array.firstIndex(of: element)
    }

    func lastIndex(of element: Element) -> Int? {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        return array.lastIndex(of: element)
    }

    func starts<PossiblePrefix>(with possiblePrefix: PossiblePrefix) -> Bool where PossiblePrefix : Sequence, Element == PossiblePrefix.Element {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        return array.starts(with: possiblePrefix)
    }

    func elementsEqual<OtherSequence>(_ other: OtherSequence) -> Bool where OtherSequence : Sequence, Element == OtherSequence.Element {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        return array.elementsEqual(other)
    }

    func contains(_ element: Element) -> Bool {
        _wait(); defer { _signal() }
        return array.contains(element)
    }

    static func != (lhs: AtomicArray<Element>, rhs: AtomicArray<Element>) -> Bool {
        lhs._wait(); defer { lhs._signal() }
        rhs._wait(); defer { rhs._signal() }
        return lhs.array != rhs.array
    }

    static func == (lhs: AtomicArray<Element>, rhs: AtomicArray<Element>) -> Bool {
        lhs._wait(); defer { lhs._signal() }
        rhs._wait(); defer { rhs._signal() }
        return lhs.array == rhs.array
    }
}
```

### Usage sample 1

```
import Foundation

// init
var array = AtomicArray<Int>()
print(array)
array = AtomicArray(repeating: 0, count: 5)
print(array)
array = AtomicArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
print(array)

// add
array.append(0)
print(array)
array.append(contentsOf: [5,5,5])
print(array)

// filter
array = array.filter { $0 < 7 }
print(array)

// map
let strings = array.map { "\($0)" }
print(strings)

// insert
array.insert(99, at: 5)
print(array)
array.insert(contentsOf: [2, 2, 2], at: 0)
print(array)

// pop
_ = array.popLast()
print(array)
_ = array.popFirst()
print(array)

// remove
array.removeFirst()
print(array)
array.removeFirst(3)
print(array)
array.remove(at: 2)
print(array)
array.removeLast()
print(array)
array.removeLast(5)
print(array)
array.removeAll { $0%2 == 0 }
print(array)
array = AtomicArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0])
array.removeSubrange(0...2)
print(array)
array.replaceSubrange(0...2, with: [0,0,0])
print(array)
array.removeAll()
print(array)

array.set(array: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0])
print(array)

// subscript
print(array[0])
array[0] = 100
print(array)
print(array[1...4])

// operator functions
array = [1,2,3] + AtomicArray([4,5,6])
print(array)
array = AtomicArray([4,5,6]) + [1,2,3]
print(array)
array = AtomicArray([1,2,3]) + AtomicArray([4,5,6])
print(array)
```

### Usage sample 2

```
import Foundation

var arr = AtomicArray([0,1,2,3,4,5])
for i in 0...1000 {
    // Single actions
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        usleep(useconds_t(Int.random(in: 100...10000)))
        let num = i*i
        arr.append(num)
        print("arr.append(\(num)), background queue")
    }
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
        usleep(useconds_t(Int.random(in: 100...10000)))
        arr.append(arr.count)
        print("arr.append(\(arr.count)), default queue")
    }

    // multy actions
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
        arr.set { array -> [Int] in
            var newArray = array
            newArray.sort()
            print("sort(), .utility queue")
            return newArray
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile for me

Answer (score 7):

A minor detail: In Swift 3 (at least in Xcode 8 Beta 6), the syntax for queues changed significantly. The important changes to @Kirsteins' answer will be:

```
private let accessQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "SynchronizedArrayAccess")

txAccessQueue.async() {
  // Your async code goes here...
}

txAccessQueue.sync() {
  // Your sync code goes here...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## Swift-Nio & Vapor Swift

For those of you using Swift-Nio (or Vapor Swift which is based on Swift-Nio), there's a built in solution for this problem:

```
class MyClass {
    let lock = Lock()
    var myArray: Array<Int> = []

    func networkRequestWhatEver() {
        lock.withLock {
            array.append(someValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you should use the same `Lock` object when modifing the same `Array` object (or `Dictionary`, etc.).

https://github.com/apple/swift-nio/blob/5e728b57862ce9e13877ff1edc9249adc933070a/Sources/NIOConcurrencyHelpers/lock.swift#L15

Comment: ```import NIOConcurrencyHelpers```

Comment: Why would you import a whole library just for locking?

Comment: If one is using vapor swift and swift-nio already anyways, this is probably the easiest solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the answer for Swift 4,

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.readerWriter", qos: .background, attributes: .concurrent)
var safeArray: [String] = []

subscript(index: Int) -> String {

    get {
        queue.sync {
            return safeArray[index]
        }
    }

    set(newValue) {
        queue.async(flags: .barrier) { [weak self] in
            self?.safeArray[index] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use queues for locking. It just uses a lock internally and dispatches to a different thread which is completely unnecessary. Use a lock.

Answer (score 2):

I think dispatch_barriers are worth looking into. Using gcd for synchronicity is more intuitive to me than using synchronize keyword to avoid state mutation from multiple threads.

https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-10-14-whats-new-in-gcd.html

Answer (score 1):

## Approach:

Use `DispatchQueue` to synchronise

## Refer:

http://basememara.com/creating-thread-safe-arrays-in-swift/

## Code:

Below is a crude implementation of a thread safe array, you can fine tune it.

```
public class ThreadSafeArray<Element> {
    
    private var elements    : [Element]
    private let syncQueue   = DispatchQueue(label: "Sync Queue",
                                            qos: .default,
                                            attributes: .concurrent,
                                            autoreleaseFrequency: .inherit,
                                            target: nil)
    
    public init() {
        elements = []
    }
    
    public init(_ newElements: [Element]) {
        elements = newElements
    }
    
    //MARK: Non-mutating
    
    public var first : Element? {
        return syncQueue.sync {
            elements.first
        }
    }
    
    public var last : Element? {
        return syncQueue.sync {
            elements.last
        }
    }
    
    public var count : Int {
        
        return syncQueue.sync {
            elements.count
        }
    }
    
    public subscript(index: Int) -> Element {
        
        get {
            return syncQueue.sync {
                elements[index]
            }
        }
        
        set {
            syncQueue.sync(flags: .barrier) {
                elements[index] = newValue
            }
        }
    }
    
    public func reversed() -> [Element] {
        
        return syncQueue.sync {
        
            elements.reversed()
        }
    }
    
    public func flatMap<T>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> T?) rethrows -> [T]  {
        
        return try syncQueue.sync {
        
           try elements.flatMap(transform)
        }
    }
    
    public func filter(_ isIncluded: (Element) -> Bool) -> [Element] {
        
        return syncQueue.sync {
         
            elements.filter(isIncluded)
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: Mutating
    
    public func append(_ element: Element) {
    
        syncQueue.sync(flags: .barrier) {
            
            elements.append(element)
        }
    }
    
    public func append<S>(contentsOf newElements: S) where Element == S.Element, S : Sequence {
        
        syncQueue.sync(flags: .barrier) {
            
            elements.append(contentsOf: newElements)
        }
    }
    
    public func remove(at index: Int) -> Element? {

        var element : Element?

        syncQueue.sync(flags: .barrier) {
            
            if elements.startIndex ..< elements.endIndex ~= index {
                element = elements.remove(at: index)
            }
            else {
                element = nil
            }
        }
        
        return element
    }
}

extension ThreadSafeArray where Element : Equatable {
    
    public func index(of element: Element) -> Int? {
        
        return syncQueue.sync {
            elements.index(of: element)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Swift are you using ?

Comment: My bad, I wrote comment without trying to compile the code. I though that `return queue.sync { _array }` won't compile because `sync` returns nothing.

Comment: It returns array and the access to the array is synchronised.

Comment: Access to the array is synchronized, true, but any operations performed on the returned array are not.

Answer (score 1):

firstly, objc_sync_enter not works

```
objc_sync_enter(array)
defer {
   objc_sync_exit(array)
}
```

reason [objc_sync_enter / objc_sync_exit not working with DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35084754/objc-sync-enter-objc-sync-exit-not-working-with-dispatch-queue-priority-low)

objc_sync_enter is an extremely low-level primitive, and isn't intended to be used directly. It's an implementation detail of the old @synchronized system in ObjC.

for swift, should use like this, just as @Kirsteins said, and I suggest sync instead of async:

```
private let syncQueue = DispatchQueue(label:"com.test.LockQueue") 
func test(){
    self.syncQueue.sync{
        // thread safe code here
    }
}
```

Comment: serial queue with sync wont cause deadlock ?

Comment: thanks @karthik, sync did lead to deadlock in some scenario. but for my project, the queue using it has no resource dependency, so it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want thread-safe interaction with your array, you must synchronize your access. There are many alternatives suggested (and a few that have been omitted), so let us survey the various synchronization alternatives:

1. Serial dispatch queue: This is a straightforward and intuitive GCD pattern.
2. Reader-writer pattern with concurrent queue: This is an elegant refinement of the serial dispatch queue pattern, using concurrent queue with asynchronous “writes” (so the caller does not wait for the write to finish) with a barrier (to prevent any interaction concurrent with a “write”), but it offers concurrent “reads” (allowing greater concurrency during “reads”). This is a sophisticated and appealing pattern, but in practice, it is only useful if the benefits of concurrent “reads” and asynchronous “writes” outweigh the GCD overhead.
3. Locks:

   - `NSLock` is a fast and simple locking mechanism that is more performant than any of the GCD alternatives for most scenarios:

     ```swift
     extension NSLocking {
         func synchronized<T>(_ block: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
             lock()
             defer { unlock() }
             return try block()
         }
     }
     ```
   - `os_unfair_lock` is another locking mechanism, which is even faster than `NSLock`, but is a little more complicated to use from Swift. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66525671/1271826. But in those rare cases where performance is of paramount concern, unfair locks are a compelling solution.
4. The Objective-C `objc_sync_enter` and `objc_sync_exit` API: This is not of practical interest in the Swift world.
5. Semaphores: It is conceptually similar to lock-based approaches, but is generally slower than any of the lock-based approaches and can be disregarded in this conversation.
6. Actors: A synchronization mechanism provided by the Swift 5.5 concurrency system. See [Protect mutable state with Swift actors](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133/).

In short, if using `async`-`await`, actors are the logical alternative. If not yet adopting the Swift concurrency system, I would gravitate to a lock-based approach (which is simple and fast) or, in rare cases, the GCD reader-writer approach.

In practice, the choice of synchronization mechanism is not relevant in most use cases. (And if you are doing so many synchronizations that the performance difference becomes material, you might want to consider how to reduce the number of synchronization points before dwelling on the particular mechanism.) That having been said, the older synchronization mechanisms (semaphores, `objc_sync_enter`, etc.) simply would not be contemplated anymore.

---

Having outlined the possible synchronization mechanisms, the next question is at what level one performs the synchronization. Specifically, more than once, property wrappers for the entire array have been proposed. This is, invariably, the wrong place to synchronize. The property wrapper approach provides atomic access to the array (which is not quite the same thing as thread-safety), but you generally need a higher level of abstraction. E.g. if one thread is adding elements and while another is reading or removing, you often want each of these high-level tasks to be synchronized, not just the individual accesses of the array.

Answer (score 0):

[To improve the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28976644/1979882) I would suggest using defer:

```
objc_sync_enter(array)
defer {
   objc_sync_exit(array)
}
// manipulate the array
```

and the second one

```
func sync(lock: NSObject, closure: () -> Void) {
    objc_sync_enter(lock)
    defer {
        objc_sync_exit(lock)
    }
    closure()
}
```

Comment: this not works, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35084754/objc-sync-enter-objc-sync-exit-not-working-with-dispatch-queue-priority-low

Answer (score 0):

**Swift Thread safe collection**

The main and most common idea of making something(e.g. Collection) thread safe in Swift is:

1. Custom(local) **concurrent queue**
2. **Synchronous reading**. Reading a critical section(shared resource) via `sync`
3. **Asynchronous writing** with **barrier**

[[Swift Thread safe singleton]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66233444/4770877)

Answer (score -1):

There's a great answer here which is threadsafe and doesn't block concurrent reads: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15936959/2050665

It's written in Objective C, but porting to Swift is trivial.

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) dispatch_queue_t thingQueue;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject *thing;

- (id)init {
  ...
    _thingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("...", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
  ...
}

- (NSObject *)thing {
  __block NSObject *thing;
  dispatch_sync(self.thingQueue, ^{
    thing = _thing;
  });
  return thing;
}

- (void)setThing:(NSObject *)thing {
  dispatch_barrier_async(self.thingQueue, ^{
    _thing = thing;
  });
}
```

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/users/97337/rob-napier