# Background process listening to variable changes?

Tags: ios, swift, background-process, nsoperationqueue

I'm new to background operations in iOS, so I'm wondering what is the best way to solve such problem:

I have data, coming from one webservice#1 that needed to be parsed and sent to webservice#2 in background.

I need a background thread, which will be listening for changes in array that stores data from webserivce#1 and when it's not empty, the thread will start uploadOperation, which will process the array and send processed data to webservice#2

Literally, how I see it:
I have **DataManager** class, presented by a Singleton sharedInstance.

```
let sharedInstance = DataManager()
```

It has

```
public var data: [String]? {
    didSet {
        processData()
    }   
}

private var uploadToWebSerivice2Queue: NSOperationQueue?

private override init() {
    uploadToWebSerivice2Queue = NSOperationQueue()
    uploadToWebSerivice2Queue.maxConcurentOperations = 1
    getCachedAndNotSentDataFromDatabase()
}

private func getCachedAndNotSentDataFromDatabase() {
    data = ("string 1", "string 2", "string 3", "string 4")
}

private func processData() {

    while let lastElement = data!.removeLast {
        let processedData = process(lastElement)
        let uploadOperation = UploadOperation(processedData) // Data upload opeation
        uploadToWebSerivice2Queue!.addOperation(uploadOperation)
    }

}
```

Some data may come from Database where they are cached if they couldn't be send to webservice#2 during the last try. And some data may come from webservice#1 in runtime.

So in other class, let's call it **Webservice1DataHandler**, I'd do:

```
DataManager.sharedInstance.data.append("New string to process and upload to webservice#1")
```

To sum up,
*var **data*** will be set after first init() and uploadQueue will start to process that data. Then new string will be appended to *var **data***, that means that **processData()** method will be invoked and concurecny problems with **data** array access may occur.

I'm not sure if my algorithm is OK.

Comment: Why bother with the data array?  Why not simply call a method that puts another upload operation on the queue.  By using an array you have possible concurrency issues with updates to the array. So you would just say `DataManager.sharedInstance.processData(somedata)`

Comment: That's exactly what I was aware of. Invoking processData for each part of freshly arrived data didn't come in to my mind. Thanks.

Comment: @Paulw11, however, it might become a problem if I need to process freshly arrived data first. In this case I can use data array as a stack (LIFO).

Comment: Yes, but you will need to ensure that access to the array is made thread safe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191079/create-thread-safe-array-in-swift

Comment: @Paulw11 I like this approach, thanks again.