# Add sort to array wrapping class

Tags: swift

The following code is from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28191539/4096655

```
public class SynchronizedArray<T> {
    private var array: [T] = []
    private let accessQueue = dispatch_queue_create("SynchronizedArrayAccess", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

    public func append(newElement: T) {
        dispatch_async(self.accessQueue) {
            self.array.append(newElement)
        }
    }

    public subscript(index: Int) -> T {
        set {
            dispatch_async(self.accessQueue) {
                self.array[index] = newValue
            }
        }
        get {
            var element: T!

            dispatch_sync(self.accessQueue) {
                element = self.array[index]
            }

            return element
        }
    }
}

var a = SynchronizedArray<Int>()
a.append(1)
a.append(2)
a.append(3)

// can be empty as this is non-thread safe access
println(a.array)

// thread-safe synchonized access
println(a[0])
println(a[1])
println(a[2])
```

I am doing something very much like but am having trouble setting up a sort to pass to the array of generics. Ideally I'd like a sortInPlace but am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort the wrapped array, then one way is to constrain `T` to a type conforming to `Comparable`. If you add this restriction, then a sorting function is easy to implement, simply ask the array to sort itself:

```
public class SynchronizedArray<T: Comparable> {

...

public func sortInPlace() {
    array.sortInPlace(<)
}
```

For custom classes, you need to add an extension conforming to `Comparable`, and overload the `==` and `<` operators (reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Comparable_Protocol/index.html))

```
extension MyClass: Comparable {

}

func ==(lhs: MyClass, rhs: MyClass) -> Bool {

}

func <(lhs: MyClass, rhs: MyClass) -> Bool {

}

var a = SynchronizedArray<MyClass>()
```

Comment: How would I specify the property of the object to sort on?

Comment: I see it's just sorting on what's defined in the comparable conformance, that'll work, thank you!