# Thread Safe Read/Write Array access with Concurrent Dispatch Group

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, thread-safety, grand-central-dispatch

I'm developing an Photo editing application. I'm giving my users the option to import multiple assets to the edit `View Controller`. I'm creating a `Dispatch Group` for all the "PHAsset->Asset fetching" calls.
 Each time the `PHAsset` fetch request completion block called, I need to `append` the fetched asset into an `Mutable Array`, and updating the UI (1/3 imported | 2/3 imported and so on) by the amount of the imported assets.
Because Swift `Mutable Arrays` aren't thread-safe, sometimes I'm getting a crash. I guess the completion handler called from multiple threads, causing some kind of a deadlock.

### **What would be the correct way to handle thread-safe read/write Array access with Concurrent Dispatch Group?**

```
var assets = [Asset]()

func getAssetsFromPHAssets() {

    let dispatchGroup: DispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    for phAsset in phAssets {

        dispatchGroup.enter() // Enter group for each asset

        PHImageManager.default().requestPlayerItem(forVideo: phAsset, options: nil, resultHandler: { (item, info) in

            let asset = Asset(playerItem: item, position: 0)
            self.assets.append(asset)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.lblImport.text = "Importing \(self.assets.count)/3"
            }

            dispatchGroup.leave() // Leave group
        })
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
            print("finished importing")
        })
}
```

Comment: When looking through the answers in the duplicate, the [answer by mooney](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40045439/1226963) is best.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for replying. The comment on his answer looks skeptical about his solution. Can you confirm his answer

Comment: I didn't actually test it but the approach is what you need. Create a concurrent queue. Use regular sync/async to read from your array and use a barrier sync/async to write to the array. This allows multiple concurrent readers but ensures a write is done on its own and blocks and concurrent reads or writes.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks, I've implemented the answer you have linked. Now I need to think about how to test it lol. One small question, does the dispatchGroup.leave(), should be at the current location it is, or should I wrap it inside async/sync call as well?

Comment: Your calls to `leave` are fine. There's no need to move the call to `leave` inside the same block that updates the label.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks rmaddym . You helped me so much. ! :)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest adding the new Asset in the main thread:

```
let asset = Asset(playerItem: item, position: 0)

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.assets.append(asset)
    self.lblImport.text = "Importing \(self.assets.count)/3"
}
```

Maybe - but this depends on what you are doing in the `notify` closure - you should also move the `dispatchGroup.leave()` call into the main queue.