# How do I use DispatchGroup within nested Firebase asynchronous observeSingleEvent() methods Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, asynchronous, parallel-processing, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to loop through two Firebase database references, `firstRef` and `secondRef`, observe the respective values with the `observeSingleEvent` Firebase async method, and append the values to two arrays, `firstArray` and `secondArray`. Once this has been completed, I would like to notify the dispatch group and execute a completion handler. However, when the following method is called the two arrays are always **unexpectedly found nil**. I'm not too sure why this is or whether this problem arises because I have nested asynchronous functions. I know force unwrapping is also syntactically frowned upon, but, in this case, I expect the two arrays to always be populated with data retrieved from the database.

```
func loop(inputArray: [inputType], doneLoop: @escaping (_ firstArray: [firstType],_ secondArray: [secondType]) -> Void) {

    var firstArray: [firstType]?
    var nameArray: [secondType]?

    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    for element in inputArray {

        let firstRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "firstPath")

            //Enter dispatch group
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            firstRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

                //Storing first snapshot value

                let firstSnapshotValue = snapshot.value as! firstType

                let secondRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "secondPath")

                secondRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in


                    //Storing second snapshot value
                    let secondSnapshotValue = snapshot.value as? String

                    //Append retrieved values to arrays
                    firstArray?.append(firstSnapshotValue)
                    secondArray?.append(secondSnapshotValue)
                })

            })
            //Leave dispatch group
            dispatchGroup.leave()

    }

    //Notify on main queue and execute completion handler
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        doneLoop(firstArray!, secondArray!)
    }


}
```

Do I perhaps have to create a new function with an @escaping completion handler? The only problem is that since it is looping through the array, the completion will only be executed once and so only one value would have be populated.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make both `firstArray` and `nameArray`:

```
var firstArray = [firstType]()
var nameArray = [secondType]()
```

And `leave()` the `dispatchGroup` inside the innermost callback. And consider wrapping it in a `defer{}`, protecting against any multiple paths inside the callback in the future.

```
func loop(inputArray: [inputType], doneLoop: @escaping (_ firstArray: [firstType],_ secondArray: [secondType]) -> Void) {

  var firstArray = [firstType]()
  var nameArray = [secondType]()

  let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

  for element in inputArray {

    let firstRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "firstPath")

    //Enter dispatch group
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    firstRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

      //Storing first snapshot value

      let firstSnapshotValue = snapshot.value as! firstType

      let secondRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "secondPath")

      secondRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        //Leave dispatch group
        defer { dispatchGroup.leave() }

        //Storing second snapshot value
        let secondSnapshotValue = snapshot.value as? String

        //Append retrieved values to arrays
        firstArray.append(firstSnapshotValue)
        secondArray.append(secondSnapshotValue)
      })

    })

  }

  //Notify on main queue and execute completion handler
  dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
    doneLoop(firstArray, secondArray)
  }

}
```

Also, if the values from `secondRef` are independent, consider unnesting the inner `observeSingleEvent` call (and adding additional `enter()` and `leave()` calls).

### Concurrency consideration

As is, your code will potentially/eventually lose writes to both `firstArray` and `secondArray`. The faster Firebase's `observeSingleEvent` executes its `with` block, the sooner the data will be lost. To avoid this, all writes (`append`s) should be done from a serial queue:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "tld.company.app.queue")
queue.async() {
  // Write
}
queue.sync() {
  // Read
}
```

Or, even better, keep reads concurrent with the `.barrier` flag:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "tld.company.app.queue", attributes: .concurrent)
queue.async(flags: .barrier) {
  // Write
}
queue.sync() {
  // Read
}
```

Read more: [Create thread safe array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191079/create-thread-safe-array-in-swift)